# Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? using call function with web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether

I'm new to blockchain development, I have done some simple projects before and I had no issue in calling the functions with `web3js`, but now I'm trying to run a call function on a smart contract using `web3js` and for some reason I get this error `Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?`, I don't know what is the issue here, also all of my other tests are run successfuly, I can create a new Lottery smart contract using the LotteryFactory contract with no issue, my only problem is running the `getDeployedLotteries` function. Here is the solidity code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 */

contract LotteryFactory {
    Lottery[] public deployedLotteries;

    function createLottery(uint256 minimum) public {
        Lottery newLottery = new Lottery(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedLotteries.push(newLottery);
    }

    function getDeployedLotteries() public view returns (Lottery[] memory) {
        return deployedLotteries;
    }
}

contract Lottery {...}
```

**This is my test file:**

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli')
const assert = require('assert')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const fs = require('fs')

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider())

const { abi, bytecode } = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync('bin/contracts/LotteryFactory.json')
)

const address = '0x6fe3d597e18DC780e7FcAFe821F963946F55EcE6'

let lotteryFactory
let accounts

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  lotteryFactory = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)
})

it('gets back all deployed loteries', async () => {
    try {
      const lotteries = await lotteryFactory.methods
        .getDeployedLotteries()
        .call()
      assert.ok(lotteries)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
      assert.fail('Failed')
    }
  })
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the network where the address `0x6fe3d597e18DC780e7FcAFe821F963946F55EcE6` was deployed? Can you call other methods? Which network did you deploy to? ropsten, rinkeby, ganache,..

Comment: @Ismael, I'm on a local ganache network. all the other methods are working just fine. exept for the ones that need to be called with the `.call()` function. Anything with `.send()` works just fine

Comment: I said in another thread that if you deployed to rinkeby then you can't access it while connected to ganache.

Comment: in Rinkeby everything works just fine, but when I deploy to ganache and try to run a `.call()` function. It just gives me that error. Don't know what's the reason.

Comment: Usually it is the other way around. Are you using a recent ganache version? Do you have a repo to try? Can you try in a different computer/VM?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `createLottery` function once in your tests. Without doing that, the return value for `getDeployedLottery()` would be an empty array, which is a falsy value, so `assert.ok` would fail.

Comment: I actually have done that, before running the `getDeployedLotteries()` test. I ran `createLottery()`, which was successful. all the other tests are a success accpet for the ones that are using the `.call()` function. anything with `.send()` works just fine